# Add text to points in scatterplot from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to annotate the data points to the values in the dataframe.
The dataframe has 4 columns Returns, Volatility, ,Cl and Symbol. 
Return and Volatility are floating types and Symbol is a string type.

My code compiles but doesn't plot the graph.

```
fig,ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
Y1.plot("Return","Volatility",kind="scatter",ax=ax)
def label_point(x, y, val, ax):
    a = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    for i, point in a.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x'],point['y'],point['val'])

label_point(Y1.Return,Y1.Volatility ,Y1.Symbol, ax)
```

There is no graph output on the jupyter notebook.
Is there any otherway to solve this problem ?

Comment: `plt.show()` shows a plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest plt.show() returns nothing

Comment: Try putting `%matplotlib inline` at the beginning of your jupyter notebook

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks that worked